# Why Doesn't A Character Array Give an Unsigned Result

Tags: c++, arrays, c

In this project I am supposed to receive a packet, and cast a part of it to an unsigned integer and get both Big-Endian and Little-Endian results. Originally, I wanted to just cast a pointer inside the byte array (packet) to an unsigned integer type that would automatically put the value received in Big-Endian form, like `(uint32_be_t*)packet;` similar to the way that it's automatically put into Little-Endian form when doing `(uint32_t*)packet`.

Since I couldn't find a type that automatically did this, I decided to create my own structure called "u32" which has the methods "get," which gets the value in Big-Endian form, and "get_le," which gets the value in Little-Endian form. However, I noticed that when I do this I get a negative result from the Little-Endian result.

```cpp
struct u32 {
    u8 data[4] = {};

    uint32_t get() {
        return ((uint32_t)data[3] << 0)
            | ((uint32_t)data[2] << 8)
            | ((uint32_t)data[1] << 16)
            | ((uint32_t)data[0] << 24);
    }
    
    uint32_t get_le() {
        return ((uint32_t)data[3] << 24)
            | ((uint32_t)data[2] << 16)
            | ((uint32_t)data[1] << 8)
            | ((uint32_t)data[0] << 0);
    }
};
```

In order to simulate a packet, I just created a character array and then cast a u32* to it like so:

```cpp
int main() {
    char ary[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, (char)0xF4 };
    u32* v = (u32*)ary;    
    printf("%d %d\n", v->get(), v->get_le());
    return 0;
}
```

But then I get the results: `244 -201326592`

Why is this happening? The return type to "get_le" is uint32_t, and the first function, "get," which is supposed to return the Big-Endian unsigned integer, is performing correctly.

As a side note, this was just a test that popped into my head, so I went to the library to test it in-between classes, but unfortunately that means I have to use an online compiler (onlinegdb), but I figure it would work the same in Visual Studio. Also, if you have any suggestions as to how I could improve my code, it would be greatly appreciated. I am using Visual Studio 2019 and am allowed to use cstdlib.

Comment: `char` has implementation defined signedness. Explicitly use `unsigned char` if you don't want it to potentially interpret it as signed values.

Comment: You want `%u` for unsigned ints, `%d` is for signed ints.

Comment: @ShadowRanger So what if I receive a character array from a socket? Are all of those values unsigned characters already? That would mean I get the same result?

Comment: This is why nobody likes `printf` anymore.

Comment: `u8` -> why not `uint8_t`?

Comment: What else do you use? I hate using cout because I have to put a << between every single value... and I have to use a bunch of rules if I want to add padding. (After testing %x from SuperStormer's comment) Printf allows me to put "%08x" to show the whole hex value the same as the others, also allows me to just put "%.2f" for 2 floating points... like there is a lot to love with printf.

Comment: _This is why nobody likes printf anymore_.  This is a slightly hyperbolas statement.  Not everyone hates `printf()`

Comment: @ryyker Whoops, forgot to reformat those. I have a bunch of typedef at the top of my header file to rename "uintX_t" to u8, u16, i16, etc. like the types they use in Rust. It's just shorthand because I'm lazy.

Comment: Choose `C` or `C++`.  I do not know if the struct definition falls within the rules of `C++`, but it does not work in `C`.

Comment: @ryyker that was just my slightly humorous way of saying that `printf` is not type safe, and those that value type safety will try to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I daresay you want to use `%u` not `%d` in that `printf()` format-string!

`%d` assumes that the value is signed, so if the most-significant bit is `1` you get a minus sign.

Comment: I was not aware of this. I assumed "%d" meant "digit," as in it would output any value in it's intended form. I should probably take another look at printf..

Comment: @BrandonWoolworth the fatal flaw of `printf` is that it doesn't know the type of its arguments.  You need to be very careful to use the proper matching format codes, including any modification flags.

Answer (score 1):

There is a more elegant way to accomplish the same task. Just use `uint32_t` instead. You can use `std::memcpy` to convert between `char` arrays and `uint32_t` without invoking undefined behavior. This is what [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) does too. Reinterpreting a `char*` as an `int*` is undefined behavior. It is not the cause of your problem, because MSVC allows for it, but that's not really portable.

`std::memcpy` conversions or pointer casts will take place with native byte order, which is either little or big endian.
You can convert between byte orders using a builtin function. For MSVC, this would be:

```cpp
_byteswap_ulong(x); // unsigned long is uint32_t on Windows
```

See the [documentation of `_byteswap_ulong`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/byteswap-uint64-byteswap-ulong-byteswap-ushort?view=vs-2019). This will compile to just a single x86 `bswap` instruction, which is unlikely for your series of shifts. This can improve performance by a factor of 10x. GCC and clang have `__builtin_bswap` if you want portable code.

You can detect native endianness using [`std::endian`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian) or if you don't have C++20, `__BYTE_ORDER__` macros. Converting to little-endian or big-endian would then just be doing nothing or performing a byte swap depending on your platform endianness.

```cpp
#include <bit>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdint>

uint32_t bswap(uint32_t x) {
    return _byteswap_ulong(x);
}

uint32_t to_be(uint32_t x) {
    return std::endian::native == std::endian::big ? x : bswap(x);
}

uint32_t to_le(uint32_t x) {
    return std::endian::native == std::endian::little ? x : bswap(x);
}

int main() {
    char ary[4] = { 0, 0, 0, (char) 0xF4 };
    uint32_t v;
    std::memcpy(&v, &ary, 4);
    
    printf("%u %u\n", to_be(v), to_le(v));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Man, C++20 looks amazing. I keep seeing things that I'd love to use (namely concepts) but unfortunately not enough of them are implemented in MSVC, and I don't want to use C++20 only to learn that I can't use something. That said, I appreciate the comment. I opted not to go this route because I know that I am receiving packets, so they come in a particular order (not sure if I could detect endianness), and I can't use those macros or else I would use the winsock methods (htons, etc.).